# Cookiecutter Django project postgres migrating to new host

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, cookiecutter

I have a cookiecutter django template project working fine with a local postgres database.

(https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

I've copied the git repository and recreated the docker images on a new host to run in production, but I would like to export/copy my data as well.

What's the recommended way to move the data over from the postgres docker instance ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a `JSON` output of all database data using the `dumpdata` command in Django. Transfer the `JSON` file to your host, and then reimport the data into the database. Refer to this article for a comprehensive guide on reading detailed instructions on the entire process.

**https://cpske.github.io/ISP/django/data-import-export**

Comment: Ah that's an interesting way to do it. Also can just export from postgres I believe

Comment: I'm not sure what databases it works with, you should read Django's documentation

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out.

I re-created the docker images (cookiecutter easily re-creates them with docker compose script after I copied the source over via git, but can also manually re-create or export) and then dump directly from postgres. In the case of cookiecutter in general, can just:

```
docker-compose -f local.yml exec postgres backup
```

and then copy over from the container to host:

```
docker cp <backup> <container_name> <path - usually /backup>
```

On the new host, copy the file back and:

```
docker compose -f local.yml exec postgres restore <filename>
```

For non-docker setups, you can just run "postgres backup" directly